# Notification opening duplicate activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-notifications, onesignal

I've implemented OneSignal to send push notifications to my Android app. I've mainly implemented everything using their REST API and didn't do much code work in my app. I've followed (and literally copied the code as there was no need for much changes) [this documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-sdk-setup).

The problem is, when I'm using my app in foreground (mainactivity of my app) and I send a notificaition (which is supposed to launch the updateactivity), the activity opens on top of the current activity. Now, even when I'm tapping Exit from my app's menu, it's closing the activity on the top, however, the activity on the bottom is still there. So, basically, users have to exit from the app twice.

I have declared all activities as `<singleTask>` in the manifest.

Here's the ApplicationClass.java needed and used by OneSignal:

```
package com.application;

import android.app.Application;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public class ApplicationClass extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
    }

}
```

And here's my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.application"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".ApplicationClass"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Splash"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="domain.tld"
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:pathPattern="/*"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="domain.tld"
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:pathPattern="/*"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="www.domain.tld"
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:pathPattern="/*"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="www.domain.tld"
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:pathPattern="/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity2"
            android:theme="@style/Splash"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="domain.tld"
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:pathPrefix="/folder"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="domain.tld"
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:pathPrefix="/folder"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="www.domain.tld"
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:pathPrefix="/folder"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

                <data
                    android:host="www.domain.tld"
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:pathPrefix="/folder"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".UpdateActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".ErrorActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So, what to do to so that the new activity that opens because of the notification gets like merged into the current activity so that, when a user tries to exit, he/she can exit the app in one go?

Comment: You can try rewriting the exit button functionality to check whether any other instance of the app is running or not and then exit the app in one go.

Comment: Adding the intents like clearTop, etc. fixed the issue. I haven't updated it here yet.

Comment: using clearTop wouldn't save gracefully , this way you will have more control and save the data also.